# How to style paragraphs

Tags: css, class, text, styles, paragraph

I have 5 paragraphs in my `div` and I need to style them differently.
Is there an easier way to do it rather than giving each paragraph a different class?

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col bg-dark text-white">
                <p class="text">Nikolina Tute 2 Mount Street, Manchester M2 5WQ</p>
                <p class="text-2">#1 in Customer Service in the UK</p>
                <p class="text-3">Free Shipping for Orders over 60$</p>
                <p class="text-4">support@hlfonline.co.uk</p>
                <p class="text-5">07441 430 469</p> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You will find that using separate classes is the most simple way to individually identify divs.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a standard class and then make micro classes for the changes you want:

```
<p class="p-class"> Some Text </p>
<p class="p-class"> Some Text </p>
<p class="p-class diff-class"> I'm Different!! </p>

.p-class{
background: green;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1rem;
}

.diff-class{
"Some different stuff here"
 }
```

If you don't want to write in the class name for each paragraph than you can replace ".p-class" with just "p" 
Keep in mind this will affect all "p" elements.

 *I'm aware these aren't good class-naming conventions.*

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if each P tag needs to be accessed differently. Then yes you will need to put an ID/Class selector on each p tag. You can either use an ID on each p tag or do some type of subclasses in CSS and take advantage of the cascading effect.

```css
    .base{
        color: green;
    }

    .firstP{
        color:red
    }

    .lastP{
        color: purple;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
        <p class="base firstP">Some text</p>
        <p class="base">Some text</p>
        <p class="base">Some text</p>
        <p class="base">Some text</p>
        <p class="base lastP">Some text</p>
    </div>
```

Another thing you could do if you wanted to have cleaner markup in the HTML is nth-child selector. This way you HTML doesn't have a bunch of classes on it and all the work is done in the CSS file

```css
        #base p{
            color: green;
        }

        #base p:nth-child(1){
            color: red;
        }
    
        #base p:nth-child(5){
            color: purple;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="base">
        <p >Some text</p>
        <p >Some text</p>
        <p >Some text</p>
        <p >Some text</p>
        <p >Some text</p>
    </div>
```